Looking for online Yerushalmi Trope trainer
Need a slow speed audio with large Hebrew font to learn to lead Shabbat Shacharit and The Musaf Amidah for Shabbat in the Yerushalmi trope.

Isn't the trope for the cantillation of the Scripture?

Welcome to MiYodeya Debra and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

I am not precisely sure what you mean by the "Yerushalmi" trope in this scenario.
If you mean the Sefaradic Yerushalmi trope, you can find that and many others at the Sefaradic Pizmonim Project at: https://www.pizmonim.org/

Yes, Sefardic Yerushalmi but as a new reader with no trope reading experience
